# Convoluted tree structure causes the GC to pause indefinitely

Tags: tree, f#, closures, dispose, automatic-differentiation

I am doing some machine learning self study and currently I am implementing reverse mode [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) as practice.

The way the program works is by essentially overloading common expressions like multiplication, addition and so on and building up a tree whose nodes will subsequently be called on the backwards pass from top to bottom. This is probably the first time I used closures in F# and I quite like them, but unfortunately I am suspecting them of choking the GC, though I do not know how to verify that. I'd rather ask first here than redesign the algorithm so it does not use them as they are quite handy.

The said tree is built up many times during the program run and I am counting on the garbage collector to dispose of it.

At the bottom of the program is the main loop that trains a 2 layer net on the XOR problem. Calling GC.Collect() before the loop or after the loop and then running it again causes it to go into indefinite hiatus.

Here are the data structures I am using. I would like some advice whether my hunch is correct and I should redesign the algorithm to not use closures or whether something else is at fault.

```
type dMatrix(num_rows:int,num_cols,dArray: DeviceMemory<float32>) = 
    inherit DisposableObject()

    new(num_rows,num_cols) =
        new dMatrix(num_rows,num_cols,worker.Malloc<float32>(num_rows*num_cols))

    member t.num_rows = num_rows
    member t.num_cols = num_cols
    member t.dArray = dArray

    override net.Dispose(disposing:bool) =
        if disposing then
            dArray.Dispose()

type Df_rec = {
    P: float32 
    mutable c : int 
    mutable A : float32
    }

type DM_rec = {
    P: dMatrix 
    mutable c : int 
    mutable A : dMatrix
    }

type Rf =
    | DfR_Df_DM of Df_rec * (float32 -> dMatrix) * RDM
    | DfR_Df_Df of Df_rec * (float32 -> float32) * Rf

and RDM = 
    | DM of DM_rec
    | DMRb of DM_rec * (dMatrix -> dMatrix) * (dMatrix -> dMatrix) * RDM * RDM // Outside node * left derivative function * right derivative func * prev left node * prev right node.
    | DMRu of DM_rec * (dMatrix -> dMatrix) * RDM
```

It uses many of the functions such as the one below. The sgemm is the cuBLAS sgemm wrapper. fl out and fr out are the closures. They are convenient, but GC might find the challenging to clean up the tree.

```
let matmult (a: RDM) (b:RDM) =
    let mm va vb =
        let c = sgemm nT nT 1.0f va vb
        let fl out = sgemm nT T 1.0f out vb // The derivative with respect to the left. So the above argument gets inserted from the right left. Usually error * input.
        let fr out = sgemm T nT 1.0f va out // The derivative with respect to the right. So the above argument gets inserted from the right side. Usually weights * error.
        DMRb(DM_rec.create c,fl,fr,a,b)
    let va = a.r.P
    let vb = b.r.P
    mm va vb
```

Ideally, I would reuse the tree, but as AD could propagate error gradients through loops and branches that is not an option and the program has to do a lot of dynamic allocation even if it slow. Any advice of how to dispose of these trees efficiently?

Thanks.

Here is the link to the [Github page](https://github.com/mrakgr/ML-Dump/tree/master/AD) with the full program.

Edit: I've converted the code to not use closures and yet it still crashes upon garbage collection. I am not sure what is going on under the hood.

Edit2: It finally occurred to me to use the debugger and I see that I am getting 'System.AccessViolationException' thrown by the Alea library. It might be related to the earlier error I reported in the sum module. In fact I saw a misaligned access one or twice before, but my brain just ignored it for some reason. I'll try to isolate the error tomorrow.

Edit3: Resolved the issue. It was due to the faulty Alea reduce module and had nothing to do with closures or the tree structure that I was using.

Also I've verified that there is no reason not to use closures as they do not involve any kind of performance penalty compared to explicitly passing along the parameters. That is nice and surprising.